# Load a page freshly and not from the cache with php

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, browser, meta-tags

I just ported a development version of my site over to production and it's still showing old images and using ancient stylesheets. This is happening to everyone.

I tried

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma-directive" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Directive" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
```

Also, because this is WordPress I just enqueue the css which adds the theme version at the end. so style.css?ver=2.0.

I'm running this on IIS out of corporate necessity.

None of these options seem to work properly. How can I load the page freshly and not from cache when users visit the site?

Comment: Why not adding wordpress to your tags, as you are basically asking: "How to turn off caching in wordpress?" For that you will most likely get a more targeted answer from http://Wordpress.stackexchange.com Also, maybe helps: http://codex.wordpress.org/I_Make_Changes_and_Nothing_Happens

Comment: It didn't have anything to do with WordPress. It was related to IIS caching.

Comment: Then maybe you should add IIS in the tags and not meta-tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're in a PHP page, just append a random number to the request

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?random=<?php echo rand(1,100000); ?>" />
```

You can also do it with PHP headers inside the CSS/JS/etc files, but then you need to parse CSS and JS as PHP and it gets a bit messy.

The other option is to set it up via htaccess - courtesy of http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks! Because this is WordPress I just enqueue everything through which adds the theme version at the end. so style.css?ver=2.0. I'm running this on IIS so adding this to .htaccess won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247389 This may mean something to you, I have no clue about IIS, so hey :) Googling for "IIS disable caching" should give you some good results though.

Comment: @Zach Shallbetter: Side note, as you've not come back to this I assume it's solved. If so, please click the big tick by this answer to choose as the selected answer :) If you don't choose answers as selected, people are less likely to answer future questions you ask :)

Comment: Lol, I was still working on the issue. I've very persistent on other stack exchange sites.

Comment: Heh, fair play :) I've just decided that if an asker has low rep and I think the question looks solved, I'm poking them just as a friendly reminder :P

Answer (score 0):

Because it's WordPress:

Try the Style.css Last Version plugins for WordPress, it prevents CSS caching like a charm. https://wordpress.org/plugins/stylecss-load-last-version/

Cheers,